# Redux React. Connect doesn't update state of component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a problem with using Redux. I have created Reducer and it works fine, But the component state does not update.
I saw some answers with similar problems but solutions don't work for me.

Reducer1:

```
export default (state = null, action) => {
switch (action.type) {
    case 'select_library':
        return action.payload
    default: 
        return null;
}
}
```

Reducer2:

```
import data from './LibraryList.json';

export default () =>  data;
```

reducers:

```
export default combineReducers({
libraries: LibraryReducer,
selectedlibraryId: SelectionReducer
});
```

Action:

```
export const selectLibrary = (libraryId) => {
return {
    type: 'select_library',
    payload: libraryId
};
}
```

App:

```
const store = createStore(reducers);

const App = () => {
return (
    <Provider store={store}>
        <View style={{ flex: 1}}>
            <Header headerText="Tech Stack" />
            <LibraryList />
        </View>
    </Provider>
)
}

export default App;
```

LibraryList (works fine):

```
class LibraryList extends Component {
renderItem(library) {

    return <ListItem library={library} />
}

render() {
    return (
        <FlatList 
            data={this.props.libraries}
            renderItem={this.renderItem}
            keyExtractor={(library) => library.id.toString()}
        />
    )
}
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
   return { libraries: state.libraries }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(LibraryList);
```

ListItem (problem here) is not call render after click ( click call `mapStateToProps` ):

```
class ListItem extends Component {
renderDescription() {
    const {library, selectedLibraryId } = this.props

    if (library.item.id === selectedLibraryId) {
        return (
            <Text>{library.item.description}</Text>
        )
    }
}

render() {
    const { titleStyle } = styles
    const { id, title } = this.props.library.item
    return (
        <TouchableWithoutFeedback 
            onPress={() => {
                this.props.selectLibrary(id)
            }
        }
        >
            <View>
                <CardSection>
                    <Text>
                        {title}
                    </Text>
                </CardSection>
                {this.renderDescription()}
            </View>
        </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
    )
}
}
const mapStateToProps = state => {
return { selectedLibraryId: state.selectedLibraryId }
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps, actions)(ListItem);
```

Comment: I don't understand this line ListItem (problem here) is not call render after click ( click call mapStateToProps ):. May I know which click are you referring to?

Comment: reducer 2 is very unusual to be a reducer

Comment: @Think-Twice in <TouchableWithoutFeedback />, as you can see above there are calling 'selectLibrary' action

Comment: @JoeyGough is no problem with reducer2, thanks

Answer (score 0):

i guess you are missing mapDispatchToProps function which will dispatch your action to reducer.? Something like this:

```js
const mapStateToProps = state => {
return { selectedLibraryId: state.selectedLibraryId }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    onLibraryClick: (id) => {
      dispatch(actions.selectLibrary(id))
    }
  }
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ListItem);
```

Comment: Thanks, but i get new one error 'TypeError Cannot read property 'item' of undefined'

Comment: Ok, it has to be this line tho: const { id, title } = this.props.library.item u r not propably passing library prop to ListItem. But i am not sure how look like FlatList Component. Just ensure that you are calling renderItem there correctly.

Comment: before adding this code in LibraryList i had library in  'this.props', now i have {onTodoClick: f}

Comment: yes, that is exactly what mapDispatchToProps do. it will add provided function to your props with scoped dispatch function. Can u add sample of FlatList component please.? Btw your component props should look something like this now: definitely: props = {onLibraryClick: f, selectedLibraryId: "id"} and meybe library property which have to be provided by parent component.?

Comment: What was the problem if i can ask.?

Comment: you will not believe, just copy-paste in new file. Run and it works! @Pavel Kratochvil

Comment: xD) its really strange I know